# Semantic UI initialize popup on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, semantic-ui

I'm trying to trigger popup module on click event:

Here is my html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>Third</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and here is js:

```
$(document).on('click', 'table td', function() {
    $(this)
      .popup({
        title    : $(this).text(),
      });
});
```

But for some reason nothing happens.

Comment: Which jQuery plugin are you using to provide the popup function?

Comment: It says in the title Semantic UI http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Well the syntax all looks correct, what error are you getting back from the inspector?

Comment: Nothing in inspector.

Answer (score 4):

You can choose the event used to trigger popup by specifying it in the settings :

```
    $(document).on('click', 'table td', function() {
    $(this)
       .popup({
           title: $(this).text(),
            on:'click'
       })
       .popup('show');
});
```

here is a working [demo](https://codepen.io/SaadRegal/pen/vZJNwm?editors=1010) .

it can be either like: focus,hover. for more settings see : http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#/settings

Answer (score 1):

Probably it was initialized but not shown.

Try to add `show` behavior:

```
$(document).on('click', 'table td', function() {
    $(this)
       .popup({
           title: $(this).text(),
       })
       .popup('show');
});
```

Docs http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#behavior